# pickmeup plugin of jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I want the calendar to show as soon as I click the input textbox. I searched everywhere but couldn't get any help. I would be really appreciated if you will help me as I am a beginner.

Here is my code:

```
<link href="CSS_File/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS_File/pickmeup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $(function () { 
            $('.Reservation .demo').pickmeup({ flat: true }); 
            var input= $('input'); 
            input.pickmeup({ position: 'right', before_show: function(){
                input.pickmeup('set_date', input.val(), true);
            }, change: function(formated){
                input.val(formated);
            }});
        }); 
    });
</script>
This is my asp.net code
<div class="Reservation"> 
    <p style=" float:left; font-size:24px;">Check In:</p> &nbsp;
    <input  type="text" style="width: 160px; height: 22px" value="17-11-2013" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your line "$('.Reservation .demo').pickmeup({ flat: true }); " refers to an element with class "demo" but you have no element with that class.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () { })` and `$(function(){})` are [the same thing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) - use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone through with your code and this library, now the mistake you are making is you are using this library as jQuery plugin, this is not jQuery based plugin, that's why if you want to initialize the calendar with your input then use it like this: `pickmeup('input', <optionObj>);`,

Also one of your line is not making any kind of sense, as your requirement is to display the calendar when user click on input, and the line of code which you written :

```
$('.Reservation .demo').pickmeup({ flat: true })
```

first of all there is no `demo` class under `Reservation` dom, and another thing is as per the pickupme framework, if you want to show a calnder on UI (which will replace your UI element with the calander) then you need to initilize it same not as jquery plugin, below example

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp/master/css/pickmeup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp/master/dist/pickmeup.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        pickmeup('.Reservation',{ flat: true });         
    });
</script>
This is my asp.net code
<div class="Reservation"></div> <!-- it will replaced as calander on UI -->
```

BTW, here your Code, which I refined and it is started showing calendar:

#### Solution:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp/master/css/pickmeup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp/master/dist/pickmeup.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('.Reservation .demo').pickmeup({ flat: true }); 
        var input= $('input'); 
        pickmeup('input',{ position: 'right', before_show: function(){
            input.pickmeup('set_date', input.val(), true);
        }, change: function(formated){
            input.val(formated);
        }});
    });
</script>
This is my asp.net code
<div class="Reservation"> 
    <p style=" float:left; font-size:24px;">Check In:</p> &nbsp;
    <input  type="text" style="width: 160px; height: 22px" value="17-11-2013" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,it worked. I just want my checkout date to select the next date of the check in date by default and I want the previous date to get blur so that user won't be able to select it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JS Date function to add 1 day in the Check in date and to blur or fade out the previous date use disabled attribute.

Comment: I am getting errors while doing this. So would you please help with the code as I am a beginner. Please...

Comment: Accept this answer if it helps you so it can be helpful to other users as well. For your further queries probably you can start a new thread (new question), it may not be good to having a discussion in Comments.

Comment: Okay,Thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will reach your requirement.. apply css for styles.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```